# Xcode Cocoa application using all code, no nibs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I want to make a Cocoa Application ViewController using all code in Xcode, not using the Interface Builder.

I have searched a lot on this and have not found anything since most people want to use the Interface Builder. I have asked this question other places, but I didn't get any answers.

Please don't say anything like "Don't waste your time on it", "They did the work for you, why do it yourself?", etc., like most people. When I make applications, I like to use all code.

I want to do this using Objective-C.  I think that is the only way, anyway.

So, can you explain how to do this or post a link?

Comment: This is certainly possible, but your question is too broad. Do you want to know how to create every kind of view in code? You should have a more specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: There's nothing to know. Just create everything in code. I do all iOS apps with just code. There's nothing special to know. Create your view controllers in code. Create and add your controls in code.

Comment: I fixed it to only viewcontroller

Comment: so it will be less broad

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create Cocoa interfaces without Interface Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717442/how-do-i-create-cocoa-interfaces-without-interface-builder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, many people prefer to create their UIs programmatically rather than with Interface Builder -- .xib files don't play well with version control. For a start, you can make a custom UIViewController Class, and use something like the following in your App Delegate's application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

```
    CustomViewController* myCustomViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = myCustomViewControllerObject;
```

You can set up your custom view controller class in its init, viewDidLoad, and other methods to suit your needs. To add most interface elements, you initialize them with their appropriate method (initWithFrame: for views, for example) then add them to your viewController's view. There are many ways to do this, but eventually you will call the addSubView: method of the UIView you want to add to. To imitate linking an IBAction for most UI elements, you call           addTarget: action: forControlEvents:, and implement the selector you pass for the action parameter. Here is an example of an init method for a UIViewController:

```
-(id) init 
{
   (if self = [super init]) {
     UIButton* addSelectedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [addSelectedButton setTitle: @"Some Button Title" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    addSelectedButton.frame = CGRectMake(sizeForTable.size.width/2 - 100 , sizeForTable.size.width/2 + 40, 200, 40);
    [addSelectedButton addTarget: self action: @selector(addSelectedButtonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubView: addSelectedButton];
}

return self
} 

-(void) addSelectedButtonPressed: (UIEvent*) event 
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this.  So, do I just leave the .xib file alone?

Comment: @retsgorf297 You don't create any xib files. Delete any that are created automatically when you create a new project.

Comment: Do you know of a link that I can learn more on?

Comment: What kind of project should I create?

Comment: @retsgorf297: There is only one kind of project (different Xcode versions aside). All of the templates are just that—templates, prepopulated with targets and files that you can change or delete at will. Start with whatever template is closest to the project you want to end up with.