# View-based NSOutlineView without NIB?

Tags: nstableview, nsoutlineview, appkit, nstablecellview

`NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView`. And currently, `NSTableView` supports two implementations.

- Cell-based.
- View-based.

To make OSX 10.8 Finder style side bar (**with automatic gray Icon styling**), need to use view-based table view with source-list highlight style.

With NIBs, this is typical job. Nothing hard. (see [SidebarDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010893-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)) But I want to avoid any NIBs or Interface Builder. I want make the side bar purely programmatically.

In this case, I have big problem. AFAIK, there's no way to supply prototype view for specific cell. When I open `.xib` file, I see `<tableColumn>` is containing `<prototypeCellViews>`. And this specifies what view will be used for the column. I can't find how to set this programmatically using public API.

As a workaround, I tried to make cell manually using `-[NSTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:]` and `-[NSTableView viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:]`, but none of them returns view instance. I created a `NSTableCellView`, but it doesn't have image-view and text-field instances. And I also tried to set them, but the fields are marked as `assign` so the instances deallocated immediately. I tried to keep it by forcing retaining them, but it doesn't work. `NSTableView` doesn't manage them, so I am sure that table view don't like my implementation.

I believe there's a property to set this prototype-view for a column. But I can't find them. Where can I find the property and make system-default `NSOutlineView` with source-list style programmatically?

Comment: The documentation of NSOutlineView is generally sparse and incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow the example in `SidebarDemo`, they use a subclass of `NSTableCellView` for the detail rows. In order to emulate the **InterfaceBuilder** mojo, you can hook everything together in the constructor. The rest is the same as the demo (see `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:`).

```objc
@interface SCTableCellView : NSTableCellView
@end

@implementation SCTableCellView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
  [self setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
  NSImageView* iv = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 6, 16, 16)];
  NSTextField* tf = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(21, 6, 200, 14)];
  NSButton* btn = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 3, 16, 16)];
  [iv setImageScaling:NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown];
  [iv setImageAlignment:NSImageAlignCenter];
  [tf setBordered:NO];
  [tf setDrawsBackground:NO];
  [[btn cell] setControlSize:NSSmallControlSize];
  [[btn cell] setBezelStyle:NSInlineBezelStyle];
  [[btn cell] setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
  [[btn cell] setFont:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];
  [[btn cell] setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
  [self setImageView:iv];
  [self setTextField:tf];
  [self addSubview:iv];
  [self addSubview:tf];
  [self addSubview:btn];
  return self;
}

- (NSButton*)button {
  return [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:2];
}

- (void)viewWillDraw {
  [super viewWillDraw];
  NSButton* btn = [self button];
  ...
```

Comment: Yep. Basically, provide your view class. Make your delegate aware of your view class. Make sure your view class knows how to align itself and its subviews as they are added and removed from the OutlineView. That doesn't make outline views any easier. They're still a PITA.

Comment: This works! Magic! The key to make it work is adding text-view and image view as subviews of the `NSTableCellView`. Also I shouldn't touch frame and autoresizing stuffs at all. NSOutlineView will not layout them properly if I touch them.

Answer (score 5):

Here's @jeberle's code re-written in Swift 4 (five years later!):

```
class ProgrammaticTableCellView: NSTableCellView {
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        self.autoresizingMask = .width
        let iv: NSImageView = NSImageView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 6, 16, 16))
        let tf: NSTextField = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(21, 6, 200, 14))
        let btn: NSButton = NSButton(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 3, 16, 16))
        iv.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyUpOrDown
        iv.imageAlignment = .alignCenter
        tf.isBordered = false
        tf.drawsBackground = false
        btn.cell?.controlSize = .small
        // btn.bezelStyle = .inline                  // Deprecated?
        btn.cell?.isBezeled = true                   // Closest property I can find.
        // btn.cell?.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn) // Deprecated?
        btn.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)
        btn.cell?.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
        btn.cell?.alignment = .center

        self.imageView = iv
        self.textField = tf
        self.addSubview(iv)
        self.addSubview(tf)
        self.addSubview(btn)
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var button: NSButton {
        get {
            return self.subviews[2] as! NSButton
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I found a link (that will inevitably rot away – it was last revised in 2011) to Apple's [SidebarDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) that @jeberle based his code on.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@jeberle 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20207110/246776), I need to note something more.

- The key to keep the text-field and image-view is adding them as subviews of the `NSTableCellView`.
- Set `NSTableView.rowSizeStyle` to a proper value (non-`Custom` which is default value) to make the table-view layout them automatically. Otherwise, you have to layout them completely yourself.
- Do not touch `frame` and `autoresizing` stuffs if you want to use predefined `NSTableViewRowSizeStyle` value. Otherwise, the layout might be broken.
- You can adjust row-height by providing `private func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, heightOfRowByItem item: AnyObject) -> CGFloat` delegate method. Setting `NSTableView.rowHeight` is not a good idea because it needs `NSTableView.rowSizeStyle` set to `Custom` which will turn off cell text/image layout management provided by default.
- You can reuse row/cell views by settings `NSView.identifier` property. ([example](https://github.com/Eonil/CocoaProgrammaticHowtoCollection/blob/6dfad6c9f2fc059ce9cbe7dedbbea00304871fb2/ComponentUsages/NSTableViewExample/main.swift))

Comment: Thank you for the link to your gist. I needed to see NSView.identifier being set when makeView() returned nil to make my non-nib tableview work.